# ExactTarget v5 Salesforce Integration - Tracking Analytics and Using Campaigns

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, bestpractice, campaign, massemailmessage

My organization recently started using the v5 ExactTarget integration with Salesforce and I'm wondering if there are some best practices on using Campaigns with ExactTarget. At this point, we only use Campaigns for our email Campaigns, though this could change in the future. Here are some specific questions:

- We aren't able to display Campaign Email analytics on the Campaign record, except for  through the Email Sends related list, where we'll click the Email Send Number and view specific analytics for that email send. Is there a way to view analytics for all email sends to a Campaign, outside of creating a report that tracks this?
- Is it useful, as far as data tracking goes, to use Parent Campaigns? I haven't found a great reason to do this as far as email campaigns go, besides tracking a hierarchy of Opportunity information.
- Is there a way to send to multiple audiences per campaign, or a work-around to doing this? We could possibly create a parent Campaign and then create separate child Campaigns for each audience/email send, but it seems like the only benefit of doing this would be to have an updated Total Contacts field on the parent.

I'd love to hear any best practices related to ExactTarget, Campaigns, and the questions above.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to speak with an ET marketing consultant.  Unfortunately, they almost never lurk in this forum.  Consider calling your ET Account Representative to arrange such an engagement.